# Payment gateway providers in Abu Dhabi - UAE

Tags: ecommerce, payment-gateway

I have been tasked with setting up a reasonable size ecommerce site in Abu Dhabi (united arab emerites). It seems PayPal Pro is not available in this region. I was wondering if any one could share some experiences working in e-commerce in this region. Also any good payment gateway providers in this region.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have lots of options for payment processors. I am sure banks in the UAE offer payment processing:

http://blog.jadopado.com/understanding-online-payments-in-the-uae/

But if you don't like local banks almost all international payment processors can be used. A few that I know off:

authorize.net

2checkout.com

cdgcommerce.com

By the way it's United Arab Emirates not emerites.

Answer (score 1):

Your options will be limited due to the high amount of fraud that occurs in that region. [Worldpay](http://www.worldpay.com) seems to be the only provider of note that offers payment services in that region.

Comment: hey, thanks for your response. Are you sure world pay offers this service in the UAE. It doesn't appear to on their website.

Comment: Do you have any source to back up your claim that Abu Dhabi is a source of lots of fraud? The UAE is one of the richest countries on the planet.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a more up to date blog answering this questions. It breaks it down to the 4 best options. 
http://www.craniumcreations.com/Dubai-Website-News/payment-gateway-options-in-dubai-and-uae/

**Payfort**

- Setup fees for small and medium enterprises (SME) is AED 3500 while
  corporate account is AED 6500
- Annual fees or AED 3500 for SME and AED 6500 for corporate
  3.0% + AED 2 per transaction
- 18 currencies accepted including AED and USD
- Additional features such as fraud protection at additional costs

**2CheckOut**
 - No setup fee
 - No recurring fees
 - 5.5% + USD 0.45 per transaction
 - 20+ currencies accepted including AED and USD

etc 
more info in article

Comment: Please summarize or provide excerpts from links in case they become no longer available, and disclose if they're from your site.